# assignment operator for class derived from std::exception

Tags: c++, inheritance, assignment-operator

I derived a custom exception class from `std::runtime_error`

static analyzer is giving me a warning that if I define or delete default operation (copy ctors, copy/move operators, destructors etc..), I should define or delete them all.

to resolve this silly warning, I wrote the missing assignment operator but then I got another warning that now my operator hides the base non virtual assignment operator!

Since base class has private members which I cant copy it looks like the only solution is to invoke base asignment operator directly for base object part and the copy the rest of `*this` object and finaly return `*this`

but before doing that I took a look on what the base `operator=` does and here what it looks like:

```
exception& operator=(exception const& _Other) noexcept
{
    if (this == &_Other)
    {
        return *this;
    }

    __std_exception_destroy(&_Data);
    __std_exception_copy(&_Other._Data, &_Data);
    return *this;
}
private:

    __std_exception_data _Data;
};
```

Now knowing that Here is my implementation (with comments) to invoke base asignment and the copy the rest of the derived object:

```
class Exception :
    public std::runtime_error
{
public:

    // ...

    Exception& operator=(const Exception& other)
    {
        if (this == &other)
        {
            return *this;
        }

        // first copy only base class data to *this
        *dynamic_cast<std::runtime_error*>(this) =
            runtime_error::operator=(
                *dynamic_cast<std::runtime_error*>(
                    const_cast<Exception*>(&other)));

        // then copy derived class data to *this
        mInfo = other.mInfo;
        mCode = other.mCode;

        // finally return complete copy
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::error_code mCode;
    std::string mInfo;
};
```

Is this correct way to do this? I think this looks like trouble but I'm not sure.

**EDIT**

here is complete class, for reference:

```
#pragma warning (disable : 4275)    // base needs to have DLL interface
    class ERROR_API Exception :
        public std::runtime_error
    {
    public:
        ~Exception() noexcept;  // cant be inlined in release build

        // default/delete
        Exception(const Exception&) = default;
        Exception(Exception&&) = delete;

        Exception& operator=(const Exception& other)
        {
            if (this == &other)
            {
                return *this;
            }

            // copy base class data to *this
            *dynamic_cast<std::runtime_error*>(this) =
                runtime_error::operator=(
                    *dynamic_cast<std::runtime_error*>(
                        const_cast<Exception*>(&other)));

            // copy derived class data to *this
            mInfo = other.mInfo;
            mCode = other.mCode;

            return *this;
        }

        Exception& operator=(Exception&&) = delete;

        /** Construct from error enum */
        template<typename Enum>
        Exception(Enum err_enum);

        /** Construct from error enum and string*/
        template<typename Enum>
        Exception(Enum err_enum, String message);

        /** Construct from error_code object */
        inline Exception(std::error_code err_code);

        /** Construct from error_code object and string */
        inline Exception(std::error_code err_code, String message);

        /** Get error_condidtion name */
        inline virtual std::string ConditionName() const;

        /** Get error_category name */
        inline virtual std::string CategoryName() const;

        /** Get error_condition value */
        inline virtual int ConditionValue() const noexcept;

        /** Get error_condition value */
        inline virtual int ErrorValue() const noexcept;

        /** Get additional information string passed to constructor */
        inline virtual const String& GetInfo() const noexcept;

        /** Get error_code object associated with this exception object */
        inline virtual const std::error_code& code() const noexcept;

    private:
        SUPPRESS(4251);     // member needs to have DLL interface
        std::error_code mCode;
        SUPPRESS(4251);     // member needs to have DLL interface
        String mInfo;
    };
#pragma warning (default : 4275)    // base needs to have DLL interface
```

Comment: So why do you need to implement or delete any special member? This looks like a fine Rule Of Zero class.

Comment: Please post the original class before you started adding stuff to it, just the basics, maybe it's OK as-is and your static analyzer (which?) is being overly aggressive.

Comment: Firstly, the static analyzer gave you two possible ways to fix this. I think you picked the wrong one, deleting these would be my choice. That said, all that dynamic_cast stuff isn't necessary, just remember that `operator=` can be invoked as a method, too, so you just call `runtime_error::operator=(other)` to dispatch to the base class.

Comment: @aschepler because I had to define destructor in source file, and I defined it because of warning that destructor was not inlined in release build. using msvc analyzer on 90% rules enabled. this sounds like crazy but I just want clean build with no warnings.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I got warning that implicitly defined destructor was not inlined, so I defined it in source file, then got the warning that I should implement the rest and so warning after warning ...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks, I'll take your advice to `just call runtime_error::operator=(other) to dispatch to the base class` that sounds logical.

Comment: Your code explicitly deletes copy and move constructors, but defines an `operator=()`. That presumably triggers the warning. Can you explain why it even makes sense to you that your class has an assignment operator, but no copy or move constructor? It makes no sense to me, since a class that may be thrown as an exception needs a copy constructor (and that copy constructor cannot throw, which generally disallows allocating resources). If inheriting from `std::exception` (or a standard classes derived from it) the default-generated copy constructor is usually all that is needed. Not deleting it.

Comment: @Peter I haven't completed other default operations yet, Its not supposed to stay so. using default asignment as you suggested trigers `Operator 'Exception::operator=' hides a non-virtual operator` and this sounds like base class would not be copied properly? I that correct? or can I ignore the warning? will the base be copied as expected if my defaulted operator hides base operator?

Comment: If you intend to implement other default operations, then let the compiler define them until you're ready to define your own. At most, define them as a stub that you can complete later. In any event, the hiding warning is probably because your `operator=()` is inconsistent with the inherited one.   `std::exception`s `operator=()` has a `throw()` specification (before C++11) or `noexcept` (C++11 and later). Your derived class needs to be consistent with that - otherwise your `operator=()` does, according to the standard, hide the base class version.

Comment: thanks! adding `noexcept` did the trick but only for assignment operator, however base does not have explicit move operator, if I omit mine I got warning that I should define it, if I defined it or make it default it tells me that it hides base operator= I'm tired of trying to make these warning go away :)

Comment: Given that your static analyser is distinct from the compiler and its library (which is where `std::exception` and derived classes are defined), there's probably not much you can do about that.  Simply record the fact that the static analyser gives a warning, and that you've decided it's acceptable (i.e. a false positive).   If your static analyser supports such things, add an annotation to your `Exception` class to prevent the static analyser giving warnings about it.  You'll need to read documentation for your static analyser to determine if that is possible and, if so, how.

Comment: @Peter I have figure out what was the problem!, I had to explicitly append `noexcept(false) = default` to move constructor to avoid warning! (updated my answer) again thank you pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to great comments from Ulrich Eckhardt, Peter and others here is how I made it work, result is no warning at all:

```
class Exception : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    ~Exception() noexcept;  // can't be inlined in release build (defaulted in source)

    // default/delete
    Exception(const Exception&) noexcept = default;
    Exception(Exception&&) noexcept = default;
    Exception& operator=(const Exception&) noexcept = default;
    Exception& operator=(Exception&&) noexcept(false) = deault;

    // the rest of the code ...
};
```

Comment: In a class where I could not delete the move-assignment but the class did not (and could not) support move semantics, I just did a pass-thru `Exception& operator=(Exception&& that) noexcept { *this = that; return *this; }` to squelch the static analyzer.  I also put in a comment explaining why the bad deed had been done, for the poor soul who has to maintain that code.